# Validating ecdsa signature in aiken

Tags: blockfrost, validator, lucid

Im trying to let my validator validate my ecdsa signature yet I get a weird JSON error:

`Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON at position 4`

My Validator for the example is simple and goes as follows:

```
type ReedemerDatum {
  oracle: VerificationKey,
  signature: Signature,
  msg: ByteArray,
}

validator {
  fn test_val(
    oracle: Void,
    redeemer: ReedemerDatum,
    context: ScriptContext,
  ) -> Bool {
    let ScriptContext { transaction, purpose } = context
    when purpose is {
      Spend(_) ->
        validate_signature(redeemer.oracle, redeemer.msg, redeemer.signature)
      _ -> False
    }
  }
}

fn validate_signature(
  key: VerificationKey,
  msg: ByteArray,
  signature: Signature,
) {
  builtin.verify_ecdsa_secp256k1_signature(key, msg, signature)
}
```

To interact with my validator I use Lucid with the following code for trying to Spend Utxos on the validator:

```
export const Redeemer = Data.Object({
  oracle: Data.Bytes(),
  signature: Data.Bytes(),
  msg: Data.Bytes()
});

export const Datum = Data.Object({
  oracle: Data.Bytes()
});

type Datum = Data.Static<typeof Datum>;
type Redeemer = Data.Static<typeof Redeemer>;


let redeemerDatum = Data.to<Redeemer>({
  oracle: "0279be667ef9dcbbac55a06295ce870b07029bfcdb2dce28d959f2815b16f81798",
  signature: "2c3ddb94fb0cc34a2d4a83d886450c6e97f1ccc769b6eb968c81a0a423bbb66a2efac027f6d62733faae43f9f7628dbfc34f004ca27af912919b00a08c18634f",
  msg: "9c478bf63e9500cb5db1e85ece82f18c8eb9e52e2f9135acd7f10972c8d563ba"
}, Redeemer);

const utxosDeposited = await queryUtxosOfAddress(
  lucid,
  validatorInformation.address,
);

let depositedUtxoRef: OutRef[] = utxosDeposited.map((x) => {
  return {
    txHash: x.txHash,
    outputIndex: x.outputIndex,
  };
});


const depositedUtxos = await lucid.utxosByOutRef(depositedUtxoRef);

const txSpend = await lucid
  .newTx()
  .collectFrom(depositedUtxos, redeemerDatum)
  .attachSpendingValidator(validatorInformation.validator)
  .complete();
const txSignedSpend = await txSpend.sign().complete();
const txHash = await txSignedSpend.submit();
await lucid.awaitTx(txHash);
```

The utxos Im trying to redeem is created as such:

```
const tx = await lucid.newTx()
.payToContract(validatorInformation.address,
   {inline: Data.void()},{ lovelace: 1000000n}).complete();
```

Lastly the way Im getting my SpendingValidator and Validator address is as follows:

```
  const updateValidator = blueprint.validators.find(
    (v) => v.title === "test_val.test_val",
  );
let spendingValidator = {
    type: "PlutusV2",
    script: toHex(cbor.encode(fromHex(validator.compiledCode))),
  };
let addressValidator = lucid.utils.validatorToAddress({
    type: "PlutusV2",
    script: validator.compiledCodessssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss,
  });
```

I'm entirely in the wild why this occurs. Any got ideas?